# Rails routing with subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have such structure of my view folders (they display logis structure):

[image: dir]

so i have subfolder in admin subfolder, that in catalogs folder i have to subfolder, manufacturer etc (manufacturer and other have there controller's with views, only catalogs and to are empty)

and rails automatically generated me such routes:

```
 namespace :admin do
   namespace :catalogs do
     namespace :to do
       namespace :manufacturers do
         namespace :models do
           namespace :types do
             resources :articles
           end
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end

 namespace :admin do
   namespace :catalogs do
     namespace :to do
       namespace :manufacturers do
         namespace :models do
           resources :types
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end

 namespace :admin do
   namespace :catalogs do
     namespace :to do
       namespace :manufacturers do
         resources :models
       end
     end
   end
 end

 namespace :admin do
   namespace :catalogs do
     namespace :to do
       resources :manufacturers
     end
   end
 end
```

manufacturers, models, types work normally, but articles work strange... When i try to write such form partial:

```
= form_for [:admin, :catalogs, :to, :manufacturers, :models, :types, @art] do |f|
  = f.label "OEM"
  = f.text_field :oem_number
  = f.label "Бренд"
  = f.text_field :manufacturer
  = f.label "Название"
  = f.text_area :name
  = f.label "Кол-во"
  = f.text_field :quantity
  = f.label "Комментарий"
  = f.text_area :details
  = f.label "Только с VIN"
  = f.check_box :only_with_vin
  = f.hidden_field :type_id, @type_id
  .form-actions
    = f.submit 'Сохранить изменения', :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

something is bad, i get 
undefined method `admin_catalogs_to_manufacturers_models_types_to_articles_path' for #<#:0xbbedf60>

but for example in types i have such form:

```
= form_for [:admin, :catalogs, :to, :manufacturers, :models, @man] do |f|  
  %b
    = @man.Name
  %br
  = @man.TYP_PCON_START.to_s[4...6].concat("-").concat(@man.TYP_PCON_START.to_s[0...4])
  \-  
  -if @man.TYP_PCON_END.blank?
    = "наст. время"
  -else
    = @man.TYP_PCON_END.to_s[4...6].concat("-").concat(@man.TYP_PCON_END.to_s[0...4])
  %br
  = ((@man.TYP_HP_FROM.to_f*0.74).round).to_i
  kW
  = f.label "Отображать в списке ТО?"
  = f.check_box :is_in_to
  .form-actions
    = f.submit 'Сохранить', :class => "btn btn-danger"
    = link_to 'Назад', :back, :class => "btn"
```

and all is ok, what's wrong with articles? How and what to change in my route and optimize it? I try a little bit, but get errors...

Comment: What does your model look like? I'm curious as to why you require so much embedding.

Comment: @mbratch forget model, it must be done so, but how?

Comment: @mbratch i have manufacturer, which has many models, models hasmany types, types hasmany articles, that's all model, i just decide to put catalog part in catalog folder, than in to. It's not the question.... Question is how to do routing... Model is written. It's carparts catalog... Very huge and private db, can't put here...

Comment: I don't think this is a good use for namespaces, which are for collecting related controllers together. You probably need nested `resources`.

Comment: @mbratch   maybe, as i write it's generated automatically...

Comment: @mbratch but if i write     namespace :catalogs do
      namespace :to do
        resources :manufacturers do 
          resources :models do 
            resources :types do
              resources :details
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end  something is bad

Comment: who is so funny and gave me -1 ?

Comment: funny peoples, better give answer

Comment: Are you saying that Rails generated the namespaces in your config/routes.rb automatically? That would be funny. ;)

Comment: @mbratch  man! it is so, i didn't create namespaces, they do automatically after my command, for example rails g controller Admin::Catalogs::To::Manufacturers::Models   i didn't edit any route! not reason for laugh

Comment: Ah I see. Cool... and apologies. I haven't generated my controllers directly that way so I hadn't seen that effect. I'm not sure what to suggest (yet) at this point other than to perhaps find an alternate way to generate the controller. Then, edit your routes to adjust the effect you are after with the embedded folders. As I mentioned, that use of namespace is a bit unconventional.

Comment: @mbratch could yo tell how to change from namespaces to resources?

Comment: @mbratch maybe you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979826/rails-routing-with-subfolders-namespaces-and-resources

Comment: I have not forgotten. I've been studying this problem when I've had some time. I'm pondering the error about `admin_catalogs_to_manufacturers_models_types_to_articles_path`. The `to` between `types` and `articles` doesn't match the example form you show. Is that form exactly the one that generates this error?

Comment: @mbratch yes, this is not trouble in to... But i solve it just deleting articles controller + view and recreating with new name :D

Comment: I would probably not use :types as :type is a reserved word in rails specific to STI. The pluralization/singularize may cause issues. It may or may not interfere here but I always err on the side of caution. I'd probably avoid :to also if you use rspec. Also as a best practice nesting more than 2 deep isn't really a ruby best practice.

Comment: please up vote me here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430963/get-value-from-http-get-response-body-via-nokogiri/19431043#19431043   :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to hold on to this nested structure, i think it is best to use nested resources instead of namespaces.

Nested resources would look like:

```
namespace :admin do 
  resources :catalogs do 
    resources :to do 
      resources :manufacturers do 
        resources :models do 
          resources :types do 
            resources :articles do
```

A form for articles would look like: `form_for [:admin, @catalogue, @to, @manufacturer, @model, @type, @article]` 
A url for the index of afticles would look like `admin_catalogs_to_manufacturers_models_types_articles_path(@catalogue, @to, @manufacturer, @model, @type)` and would generate a url like: `www.example.com/admin/catalogs/1/to/1/manufacturer/1/model/1/type/1/articles`

Note that all the parts of a url are actually instances except for admin

Comment: but then i need to define this , catalogue, to, manufacturer, model, type, article  in controller right?

Comment: Each resource will need a controller if that is what you mean, yes.

Comment: i mean you write @objects in route, need i them define in controller's method? except of for example type in types new action?

Comment: try http://192.168.1.4:3000/admin/catalogs/to/manufacturers/1213/models/1213   and get uninitialized constant Admin::Catalogs::To::ModelsController

Comment: also is it way to refactor my namespace+resources routes?

Comment: I would avoid nesting more than 2 levels.

Comment: @aceofspades it must be so!