# Get value from a HTTP GET response body via Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I get this result from a HTTP page like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Captchaservice</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    15
  </body>
</html>
```

And I use this Nokogiri code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML( response )
id = doc.xpath('//').text
```

But I get `\n 15 \n` etc.

I tried to write:

```
id = doc.xpath('//').text.to_i
```

And I get this value, but when I use this ID I get:

```
undefined method `empty?' for 15:Fixnum
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I to get this integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `id` is an instance of `Fixnum` class(as `id` holds the value 15 due to `doc.xpath('//').text.to_i`). And `Fixnum` class don't have `#empty?` method.So if you want to do empty test,then do `id = doc.xpath('//').text.strip`. Now your `id` will be having an string instance i.e. `'15'`. On this you can call `#empty?` method. when you need to use the integer value,there just do `id.to_i` and use it.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 You used in your code any where `id.empty`,but your id was 15,not `'15'`,thus you got the error `undefined method `empty?' for 15:Fixnum`.